# Android compiler compatible with WinForms

Tags: android, compiler

I have created a C# program, that we want to be installed on a mobile device. However, since we are aiming at installing this on an Android device, the .NET framework is incompatible with the Android OS.

So what is a recommended compiler for Android?

So far I have only found [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/platform) - which is compatible with Visual Studio.

**Requirements:**

- Must be compatible with Visual Studio (VS Version is not an issue - we will be upgrading to 2015 for this process)
- Must be compatible with WinForms
- Must be compatible with C#
- Must be compatible with (at least) Android, however if it allows for compatibility with other mobile OS's (iOS for example), that is also welcome.

Anything else is a bonus.

**Edit:** from the comments and some research, I have also found [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/) which *does* provide support for WinForms, however I *haven't* found any mention that this is compatible with any Android OS.

Comment: What do you mean by "mobile-based add-on"?

Comment: "Must be compatible with WinForms" sounds difficult to achieve. I hope some new solution has appeared, but here was the state of WinForms in 2013: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4759/migrate-c-winforms-code-to-android

Comment: @NicolasRaoul We have 2 programs, the main one is PC-based, and the other (that this compiler is needed for) is to be loaded onto a tablet/mobile to be used in the field. Basically, I'm just asking for a recommended compiler that will allow me to install a C# program onto a mobile Android device.

Comment: I think the question would be clearer if we focused on the program that you want to run on Android. Would you mind removing from your question things that are related only to the other program? Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul everything in the question is relevant to the program, except perhaps soecifying it's purpose, but that does not affect the question either way. It's written in C#, and needs to be compiled with something that is compatible with thd Android OS.

Comment: @Ben I had also gone through this scenario, Main application was windows based and the second one  a mobile app(android/ios/windows).I've developed an hybrid application using [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/). To develop in phonegap you must know/learn html/css/js/jquery etc for the front end development(textbox,button,grid etc), when comes to server communication I used php.